# Need help removing leading Newline in ERB Template for Chef cookbook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra

I'm using embedded Ruby version 2.3.5p376 Chef client 12.21.14.

I'm writing code that creates a standard tcp_wrappers `hosts.allow` file. The desired state is as follows

```
# This file is generated by Chef
# Do not edit, changes will be overwritten

ALL: .javajockey.com
ALL: .javajockey.local
ALL: 127.0.0.1
```

My array is stored as a role in CHEF. The following is the JSON

```
"stig": {
  "network": {
    "hosts_deny": [
      "ALL"
    ],
    "hosts_allow": [
      ".javajockey.com",
      ".javajockey.local"
    ]
  },
```

This is the contents of my Embedded ruby template

```
# This file is generated by Chef
# Do not edit, changes will be overwritten
#
<% unless @hosts_allow.nil? %>
<% @hosts_allow.each do |hosts_allow| %>
ALL: <%= hosts_allow %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

The following is the result from my code.

```
 # This file is generated by Chef
 # Do not edit, changes will be overwritten
 #
 ALL:
 ALL: .javajockey.com
 ALL: .javajockey.local

 ##############################
```

I need to remove the leading "ALL:"

Comment: Your input and output doesn’t appear to match up. Are you sure that’s what your template looks like and that you don’t have anything else manipulating those attributes?

Comment: Thanks for looking.  Just to be sure,  I pasted up code from this site and received the same result.  The attribute is coming from the role.  I can verify this since I have changed the attributes multiple times while troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: I would put some logging in your recipe, `Chef::Log.warn("hosts_allow is #{node['stig']['network']['hosts_allow'].inspect}")`. See if that shows an unexpected `nil` or similar.

Comment: If it does, please include the `attributes/default.rb` file from that cookbook, it probably has to do with some array merging issues.

Comment: As expected the array is picking up a string from somewhere.  , this is the output from the log    [2017-11-07T17:53:41-05:00] WARN: hosts_allow is ["", ".javajockey.com", ".javajockey.local", "127.0.0.1"]

Comment: What does the attributes file in the cookbook look like?

Comment: # Create /etc/hosts.allow
# An array of <net>/<mask> combinations or ['ALL']
default['stig']['network']['hosts_allow'] = ['']

Comment: There you go, fix that :)

Answer (score 0):

Tracked down in comments, cookbook default attributes had a spurious `''` in the array which was being preserved due to same-level array merging. Fix is to make the default `[]` instead of `['']`.